# PHP For loop for $_POST

Tags: php, post, foreach

Sorry for the noob question. But I am stuck here.

This is my HTML form where the user-form div can be cloned to as many as possible. The #submit-form div has some hidden values which are common for all.

HTML -

```
 <div class="user-form">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="name[]"  >
    <input type="email"  autocomplete="off" name="mail[]"  >
 </div>

 <div class="user-form">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="name[]"  >
    <input type="email"  autocomplete="off" name="mail[]"  >
 </div>

 <div id="submit-form">
    <input type='hidden' name='refer_user_id'  value='<?php echo $refer_user_id ?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='refer_user_email' value='<?php echo  $refer_user_email ?>'>
    <input type="submit"  value="Invite" />
    <input type="button" class="button" id="clonetrigger" value="Clone" />
</div>
```

I'm using ajax to submit the form. Basically I want to create accounts using the name and email fields. In PHP How do I use foreach to loop through the name and email fields so that I can create unique accounts?

My print_r($_POST); array looks like this.

```
Array
(
  [name] => Array
    (
        [0] => david
        [1] => Mark
        [2] => cindy
    )

  [mail] => Array
    (
        [0] => david@abc.com
        [1] => mark@abc.com
        [2] => cindy@abc.com
    )

  [refer_user_id] => 2
  [$refer_user_email] => test@abc.com
)
```

Comment: Looks like if you used a regular `for` loop with an index (i.e. not `foreach`) you can match up the numerical indexes, right?

Answer (score 4):

Create a loop with a number of iterations equal to the number of submitted name/email pairs, then use the loop counter to access the values for each user.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++) {
{
    $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'][$i];
    // Process the new user
}
```

Comment: don't count in the loop

Answer (score 3):

go through one of the arrays with a foreach, use the key for the second array.

```
 foreach($_POST['name'] as $key =>$name ){
    $mail = $_POST[$key];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $key => $val) {
  echo $val
}

foreach($_POST['mail'] as $key => $val) {
  echo $val
}
```

Easiest way to loop through those elements. You can reference the other elements with $_POST['refer_user_id']. While this works for the purposes of a foreach, the for loop posted above is more efficient, so I'd recommend using it.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php More reading on it here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_combine` function:

```
$data = array_combine($_POST['name'],$_POST['mail']);
foreach($data as $name=>$mail){
  print $name;
  //...
}
```

See [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the JavaScript that's auto-generating the form items to give them a name that would result in linking the php object. i.e.

```
 <div class="user-form">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="user[1][name]"  />
    <input type="email"  autocomplete="off" name="user[1][mail]"  />
 </div>

 <div class="user-form">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="user[2][name]"  />
    <input type="email"  autocomplete="off" name="user[2][mail]"  />
 </div>
```

Then you could loop through the pairs with `foreach($_POST['user'] as $key=>$value)` etc...